# Keyboard messages from child controls

Tags: c++, winapi

I am currently developing a user interface DLL that uses the WIN32 API. The DLL must work for numerous platforms, XP, WIN CE, etc. I have managed to incorporate docking, anchoring and so on but appear to have a problem regarding owner-drawn buttons. I can draw the button's correct state, focus, clicked, default. However, I cannot receive key notifications. I specifically want to perform a click operation on a button that currently has focus, should the user press enter.

Note that I am using a windows message loop rather than a dialog message loop. I use windows hooks to hook into the window creation and set the user data to 'point' to my control instance. If I test for WM_KEYDOWN in the main message loop I can get a handle to my button control instance and could forward the message to the relevant control. Unfortunately, I am dealing with a lot of legacy code and this may not be an ideal solution.

So, my question is what is the best way forward. Is subclassing the button control's window procedure a viable option or is there an easier way?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If the window has focus, it should receive key input, without need for a custom loop.  Have you investigated with Spyxx?

Comment: I agree, but I am guessing that a button control deals with key presses internally. I need to basically ensure that if the button has focus and the user presses the enter key that the 'OnClick' handler is called.

Comment: If you're using an existing control class, can't you just subclass the window proc to intercept your messages?

Comment: That was kind off what I was thinking, I just wondered if there was an easier way. Subclassing is such a pain :-)

Comment: Well, subclassing the window proc is just a call to GetWindowLong(GWLP_WNDPROC) to capture the existing proc and SetWindowLong(GWLP_WNDPROC) to wrap with your hook.

Comment: Does your owner-draw button use the standard Windows BUTTON class?

Comment: Yes true. I am guessing that all buttons share the same window proc? So, in my Button class I have static WNDPROC to hold the original button WNDPROC. I'm also guessing I can set the appropriate procs, data within the hook procedure? Years since I have done raw WIN32 development. Also, thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments above are correct.  The button with focus should be getting the key messages.  But buttons don't (by themselves) respond to Enter--they respond to Space.  It sounds like what you're missing is the typical dialog keyboard navigation, like Tab key moving the focus and Enter activating the "default" button.

If you've got a typical Windows message pump, and you want the keyboard behavior normally associated with dialogs, then you need to use the [IsDialogMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API in your message loop.  This means your window is essentially a "modeless dialog".

Comment: Thanks for the response Adrian. Problem is that the main window is just that, a window not a dialog. As mentioned, I have to work with a lot of legacy code. I am guessing that the IsDialogMessage is only appropriate if the main loop is a dialog message loop, rather than the standard winmain loop?

Comment: Apologies, I read the link that you suggested. Seems you can actually use with any window. Maybe this is the route I need to look into.

Comment: Yes, you can use it with any window.  You just have to keep track of which window (or windows) you want the keyboard behavior for, since you need to pass the window handle into the function.

Comment: Ok, So I am guessing in my main message loop that I get the window with focus and use IsDialogMessage. Apologies, like I say been many years since I developed raw WIN32 code.

Comment: No, the window with focus is likely a control like a button.  For IsDialogMessage, you want the handle of the containing window, which is probably the "main" window for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like standard window proc subclassing should do the trick.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591(v=vs.85).aspx for details.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I have to ask, if I subclass the Button control and use CallWindowProc will my subclassed button still utilize themes, etc. Not a problem currently, but maybe once I tackle Windows 7/8, etc. I only ask as I believe later Windows versions use a different method to subclassing.

Comment: Absolutely - your hook should be very non-intrusive, only observing and handling WM_KEYDOWN, etc.

Comment: ok, final question :-)
When is it best to insert my WNDPROC, following the parent notify for WM_CREATE, in my CBT hook procedure etc.
Thanks :-)

Comment: You can do it at any well-defined time before you expect to begin receiving kbd input - WM_CREATE seems reasonable.  You probably want your hook proc to uninstall itself as well, monitoring WM_DESTROY, say, to restore the original proc via SetWindowLong.

Comment: Ah yes, good point. Thanks Scott I will try out your suggestions. Who would have thought that catching a single keystroke would require so much effort :-)